# How to automatically convert a Matlab script into a Matlab function?

Tags: matlab, parsing, debugging, sed, static-analysis

My problem is the following:

I have very many (~1000) mutually calling Matlab scripts, which are very poorly written, regularly damage each other's environments and generally became unmanageable.

One of the reasons I even got this problem is that I need to write a testsuite covering a big part of them. Luckily, for most of them the main criterion of 'correctness' is 'they don't crash'.

Just running them one by one in a loop is generally not an option, because they regularly call `clear classes`, `close all`, `clc`, shadow built-in functions and operators, et cetera.

So my original aim was to find a way to run a matlab script in sort of an 'isolated environment', but I didn't find a good way to do it. (Suggestions welcome, but it is not the main question.)

Since I will need to convert them all to functions anyway, I am looking for some way to do it auto-magically, or at least semi-automatically.

What I can mean semi-automatically:

1. Just add a line `function varargout = $filename( varargin )` as the first line of the file, and `end` as the last one. This will at least make them runnable as functions with `feval` and all such functions and (more importantly) prevent them from damaging the test-runner.
2. Do point 1 and scan the file for referencing undeclared variables and add them as function arguments. This should be also doable, since the names of the variables are known. This will not help identifying output variables, but will still be a lot of help. For example, we could pack the whole workspace into one big output structure.
3. Do a runtime version of point 2. This way the 'magical converter' can actually track execution environments (workspaces) and identify which variables are implicitly used as 'input arguments' of a script, and which would be later used 'output arguments'. This option looks EXPHARD, but for a small number of calls should be not too bad in practice.

Point 1 I can implement myself using `sed`, as I also can get rid of all `clear classes` and `clc`, but the options 2 and 3 seem much harder. Is there anything at least remotely resembling options 2 or 3?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Matlab abstract syntactic tree builder? Context-free grammar?

Comment: Ultimately your problem is that all those are badly written functions  (you are aware of this), and the consequence of that is that whatever proper you may want to do with them will probably not work all the time for all cases. So truly, the only "good" option that will make sure that you can properly test them/use them as function is going through them and fixing them. Anything else will likely result in edge cases that you will need to manually hack.

Comment: Just consider what is best for your case (we don't know): Spend lots of time making sure those functions are decent 2) Spend lots of time hacking a semi-automatic way of testing them etc.  No idea which one will take longer

Comment: Regarding point 1: you don't need `end` at the end, and the name in the `function` statement at the top of the file is irrelevant. So you can just write `function func` at the top to convert a script to a function. If the scripts call each other, and scripts have "input arguments" then you'll have to fix each of the calls. Might as well fix up the whole collection manually.

Comment: Each can be run in its own workspace by calling `keyboard` before calling the script and then exiting the debug workspace when it's complete.